# ROS Answers SE migration: ROS2 version

Tags: ros, ros2, ros-bouncy, ardent

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I know which version of ROS2 have i installed ? Ardent or Bouncy Bolson ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298827/ros2-version/) by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 667 on 2018-07-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `ROS_DISTRO` envrionment variable will tell you which release you have. You can run:

```
printenv ROS_DISTRO
```

on the command line and it will tell you.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-07-27**:
And how do we know which version are we installing ? Coz i guess it is not mentioned in the installation instructions.

**Comment by [pokitoz](https://answers.ros.org/users/32070/pokitoz/) on 2018-07-27**:
I think you need to export this variable (export ROS_DISTRO=bouncy  # or ardent : https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/Linux-Install-Debians#install-ros-2-packages)

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-07-27**:
If you already have a distro of ROS2 installed then it will already be set

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-07-27**:
@aakash_sehgal It's cleared mentioned in these instructions: https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/Linux-Install-Debians#install-ros-2-packages

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-07-27**:
Yes, now I see it, I guess the documentation is updated within the last month.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-07-27**:
Yes probably, this is all moving quite fast at the moment!

**Comment by [Harsh2308](https://answers.ros.org/users/31217/harsh2308/) on 2020-08-10**:
How to know the patch release I am using?